# Proper action of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions

I am trying to prove the following:

I know that there is a proper action of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, but is it possible to construct a proper action of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$, where $n>m$?

Comment: No: properness implies point stabilizers are compact, hence trivial in this case. But there is no injective continuous map.

Comment: yes in the case where $\mathbb{R}$ act by translation, it is easy to conclude that the action of $\mathbb{R}^n$  on $\mathbb{R}^m$, where $n>m$ is not proper. but is there another way where $\mathbb{R}^n$ can act on $\mathbb{R}^m$ properly?

Comment: I didn't assume the action to be by translation. Just continuity.

Comment: @YCor how can you attempt to prove that the isotropy group of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is compact? with the assumption that the action is just continuse.

Comment: Any proper action has compact stabilizers: consider the preimage of (x,x) under the map G x X -> X x X.

Comment: I know what you mean, but how can you prove that $\{ g \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | g.x=x \}$ is not compact, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @YCor thanks, I got you now understand why you bring injective maps to our discussion thanks.

Comment: @YCor, I have proved that we can't have a proper action of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$, where $n>m$. then it follows that $\mathbb{R}^n$ can't act properly on $\mathbb{R}^m$, since $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Indeed, you can do the latter. If you have a proper action of $\mathbf{Z}^n$ on $\mathbf{R}^{m-1}$, then the quotient is a $K(\mathbf{Z}^n,1)$ and its real cohomology equals the cohomology of $\mathbf{Z}^n$, which is nonzero in degree $m$. But as an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold its cohomology vanishes in degree $n$ and we have a contradiction.